# .NET 6 EF Core 6 Hangs on SaveChanges

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I am working on a .NET 6 Winforms project that uses Entity Framework Core 6.I can retrieve data OK, but when I go to Edit data and call SaveChanges on the DbContext, it just hangs with no error. The UI freezes and when debugging, the code never steps past the SaveChanges call.

The data is actually updated in the database but it never moves past this point and I have to abort the application.

I enabled logging and I can see the SQL calls being made to EF Core 6 in the log with no errors.

I am wondering if there is some threading issue I am missing where it is not returning back to the UI, but then I would expect the debugger to at least be able to step past the SaveChanges call, but it does not. I have searched the Internet and cannot find any solution.

Here is the DbContext class;

```
public class MainDbContext : DbContext
{

    public MainDbContext(DbContextOptions<MainDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users => Set<User>();

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return result;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        return SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());
    }

}
```

Here is the User Entity class;

```
    public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? CompanyName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string? Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool? Active { get; set; }
}
```

I am using DI to handle the DbContext. Here is the AddDbContext in Program.cs

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
    {
        // Configure the app here
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        var sqlTransientErrors = new List<int>() { 10928, 10929, 10053, 10054, 10060, 40197, 40540, 40613, 40143, 64 };
        var MainDbConnectionString = "{CONNECTION STRING OMITTED}";
        var commandTimeout = "30";

        services.AddTransient<UserTest>();
        services.AddDbContext<CdiMainDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
               MainDbConnectionString,  
               sqlOptions =>
               {
                   sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30), sqlTransientErrors);
                   sqlOptions.CommandTimeout(Convert.ToInt32(commandTimeout));                                 
               }));
     })
     .UseSerilog();
```

Here is the Click event code for the Update button on the form;

```
private void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int userId = int.Parse(UserIdTextBox.Text.Trim());
    var user = _mainDbContext.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == userId);
    if (user != null)
    {
        user.Name = NameTextBox.Text;
        user.CompanyName = CompanyNameTextBox.Text;
        user.Active = ActiveCheckBox.Checked;
        _mainDbContext.Users.Update(user);
        _mainDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you overriding `SaveChanges` and implementing it via `SaveChangesAsync`? Most probably that's the reason (deadlock).

Comment: @IvanStoev Good catch. Removing the override seems to have solved the issue. The DbContext code and models are used in our .NET Core APIs. It never occurred to me that this would be a problem. Thanks. If you want to post as an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.